# Turns on but no boot OR post

Tags: boot, memory, cpu, motherboard

Today I decided to upgrade my wife's computer for her:

- ASRock 990FX Extreme4
- AMD FX-8350 4.0Ghz 8 core CPU
- 16GB Corsair DDR3 1066

I get all the parts in, hit the switch and get all the bells and whistles but no boot or post, and the debug code stays at 00 (which for this MB is listed as *Not In Use*). I did some debugging, tried different various configurations, tried booting with no RAM at all and didn't even get an error beep or anything (I thought it was supposed to be a continuous beep), same when trying to boot with no video card installed.

I've double-checked the CPU; there are no bent pins. Anyone got any ideas, is the MB bad and I have to RMA the thing?

Comment: When the booting stops? Is there a video signal? What happens if you boot without a SATA / IDE devices? Leave only the keyboard, video, processor, and a memory slot? Disable all embedded devices in the BIOS unless necessary for the diagnosis? The number of signals and the brand BIOS?

Comment: @STTR thanks for the reply, I cannot get into the BIOS the screens stay blank, I'm assuming because it isnt POSTing

Comment: reset bios and describe sound signals

Comment: Sound signals? There are no beeps at all. I tried resetting the CMOS to no avail

Comment: CPU temperature can identify? And the power supply is connected to 6 pin connector? Power in watts PSU?

Comment: PSU is a 750 watt, no way to determine CPU temp when nothing will boot/load. Yes PSU is connected with 6 pin connector on the board

Comment: Heats the CPU heatsink?

Comment: Just a tip, I'm having problems with a computer not posting had to order a POST card I'm waiting to come in, but sometimes the jumper doesn't clear the CMOS, so just in cast, try draining the CMOS battery, simple attach something that would charge via usb, unplug the computer and hold the power button down for a min or 2.

Comment: And just to confirm, you've stripped it back down to bare minimum basics it came with, reseated everything from processor to keyboard connection, tried booting without anything external plugged in, mouse keyboard, speakers, or even just speakers no monitor to see if you hear the startup sounds.

Comment: Have you checked for a possible case screw behind the mobo grounding things out?

Comment: @Justin never thought of that. I have the old parts back in it for now (she has to work) but will try again to see if it was maybe shorting out